# What is the risk of failure (cracks) when drilling in old glass?

Tags: glass

From reading on the Internet, I have learned that when cutting (scoring and breaking) glass, it almost always goes well with new glass, but with old glass there is a risk of the glass breaking in unwanted places. That is also my personal experience.

I need to to repair something, and it includes either cutting or drilling in an old piece of glass. I watched a few videos on YouTube with drilling in regular window glass, and it seems to always go well. But now I'm wondering, does it go well for them because they only work on new glass?

If I drill in my old glass what is the risk of it suddenly cracking? And if there is a risk of that, is that risk comparable to the risk of failure when cutting it? If the risk of failure with drilling is as great as the risk of failure when cutting, then I will instead try to cut.

I plan on drilling with a glass/tile bit, under constant flowing water.

I know that people on the Internet tend to answer even when they have little insight, so if you answer I would appreciate if you make it clear what you base your answer on. For instance, maybe you have worked with old glass for a decade and drilled hundreds of holes :)

Comment: For most videos you only see the one that works well, not all the practice videos.  Imagine you heard of out takes and blooper reels from movies/tv.  Learn the right tools and bits/cutters to use and how to use them.  Does not matter much between old and new glass if there is a defect in the glass that makes it break easier.  Even some new windows will shatter in place(without cutting/drilling) because there is a defect in them.

Comment: You said "drill or cut". I can't answer from experience on drilling, but I had to cut an old 1/4" (6mm) plate glass mirror and had a terrible time of it until I switched to a wet tile saw with a diamond blade. That worked well, provided I kept the feed rate agonizingly slow.

Comment: Old glass is temperamental but flowing water  should make it possible . Also using two or more sizes of bits to drill in steps helps me. For larger holes a diamond hole saw in needed.

Comment: If you have a plan B (ie, the glass broke, I gotta get a new piece), then just go for it. If that's an impossibility, then it's time to figure out an alternative approach.

Comment: In drilling I would recommend using a diamond coring bit with lots of water flowing and a very slow feed.